# Flex: six seconds between initialize and creationComplete

Tags: apache-flex, performance, canvas

I'm working with a large flex applications and I have noticed that one of our largest components (with lots of child canvases) takes about 6 seconds between the initialize and creationComplete events. I've been doing some reading and have found that having lots of nested canvases can cause slowdowns, but i'm not sure if this is where the slowdowns would be? Anyone have any suggestions on speeding this up, or even diagnosing exactly where the slowdowns are coming from?

Comment: Post some code please, thanks.

Comment: Could you post more info such as number of screens/components initialized at startup, content of these screens, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been my experience that nested containers with dynamic sizing are the most common cause of these types of lags.  Some things to try:

- Set explicit sizes/positions for your containers/components whenever possible. This reduces the incredible amount of measuring that goes on within the framework during the creation process.
- Reduce the number of nested containers.  Sounds obvious, but it's amazing how much you can cut away when you start looking critically at how your UI is set up.  Specifically, are there HBox and VBox containers you can get rid of by simply setting explicit positions/sizes for the child components?  Do you really need to use a Form container?
- Switch your containers to the much lighter weight Spark Groups instead of using the heavier weight Canvas where possible.

Hope that helps.  If not, post some code so we can dig in to your particular issue.

Comment: Also, if you have effects on your components as they are being added to the stage (fade or resize), make sure that autoLayout is set to false on the parent components - I (think I) noticed this was causing slow ups before

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing to consider is to use VBox's and/or HBox's in place of some dynamically generated x's and y's. VBox and HBox are much more efficient. Look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Adding many display objects to the display list all at once can take a long time, especially if we're talking about Flex containers that have layout and scrolling logic in the mix. Since you say you're using many Canvas containers, that could certainly be the issue you're running into.

I know that a lot of developers abuse the `creationPolicy` property. Normally, it is set to `"auto"` which allows Flex to defer instantiation of a container's children until a very short time "later". Often, before the next frame, so you don't even see the difference. Do you happen to set `creationPolicy` to `"all"` anywhere in that hierarchy? This could be forcing the Canvases and their children to be created immediately.